# How to merge two dictionaries in a list without overwriting the previous key

Tags: python, data-structures

For the dictionaries in a list, I need to extract and merge them in a single dictionary without overwriting the existing key values.

For example, I have:

```
mylist = [{'b': 3}, {'b': 9, 'A': 8, 'Z': 2, 'V': 1}]
```

The result should be:

```
{'b': 3, 'A': 8, 'Z': 2, 'V': 1}
```

Below is my code:

```
def concatenate_dict(dict_list: list) -> dict:
    final_dict = {}
    for d in dict_list:
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k not in final_dict:
                final_dict |= (k, v)

    return final_dict


mylist = [{'b': 7}, {'b': 10, 'A': 8, 'Z': 2, 'V': 1}]
print(concatenate_dict(mylist))
```

I do not understand why the "not in" keyword would not skip the existing 'b': 10 item and leave 'b': 7 alone and continue to 'A': 8

Comment: duplicate [How do I merge two dictionaries in a single expression (take union of dictionaries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-do-i-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression-take-union-of-dictionari)

Comment: Why not call `update` for the dictionaries in reverse order?

Comment: code doesn't compile, you can use `|` with a tuple

Comment: What do you mean by 'why the "not in" keyword would not skip'? The code does not even run, how can you tell if it does or does not skip anything?

Comment: Is the order important? If not, it makes the problem a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of iterating over every dictionary, how about reverse `mylist` and iteratively `update` an output dictionary? Then every key-value pair inserted into `out` from the back will be updated from the front if a key already exists.

```
out = {}
for d in mylist[::-1]:
    out.update(d)
```

Output:

```
{'b': 3, 'A': 8, 'Z': 2, 'V': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Fix

Use the appropriate operator, you can't use `|=` with a tuple

```
def concatenate_dict(dict_list: list) -> dict:
    final_dict = {}
    for d in dict_list:
        for k, v in d.items():
            if k not in final_dict:
                final_dict[k] = v
    return final_dict
```

---

#### Improve

Iterate on the dicts backwards and use `dict.update`

```
def concatenate_dict(dict_list: list) -> dict:
    final_dict = {}
    for d in reversed(dict_list):
        final_dict.update(d)
    return final_dict
```

Could be with `reduce` and merge operator

```
from functools import reduce

def concatenate_dict(dict_list: list) -> dict:
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, reversed(dict_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it, both in terms of readability and efficiency, is to iterate on your dicts in reverse order, as suggested in the **Improve** section of [azro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70612617/3080723).

However, I'd like to highlight method [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), which does exactly what you want: add a `key: value` to a dict, only if the key wasn't already in the dict.

```py
def concatenate_dict(dict_list: list) -> dict:
    final_dict = {}
    for d in dict_list:
        for k, v in d.items():
            final_dict.setdefault(k, v)
    return final_dict


mylist = [{'b': 7}, {'b': 10, 'A': 8, 'Z': 2, 'V': 1}]
print(concatenate_dict(mylist))
# {'b': 7, 'A': 8, 'Z': 2, 'V': 1}
```